# Hotkey to automatically indent and format code in Eclipse Theia

Tags: hotkeys, theia

Is there a hotkey to automatically set indentation and format code in Eclipse Theia?

I tried the hot keys of Eclipse (Ctrl + Shift + F) and VS Code (Alt + Shift + F), but neither of these work.

In case it helps, I am writing code in Rust.

Comment: In Eclipse it's Ctrl+I (if that was the reason why you tagged the question as Eclipse).

Comment: Probably not clear enough in my question : I would set the indentation and the code format on the whole file (or in a selection). It 's not only the indentation of one only block which I would achieve.

Answer (score 0):

yes, there is a hotkey for that.

To trigger the shift right/left action in Theia select a block of code and use the shortcut cuts are `Tab` and `Shift+Tab`.

Answer (score 0):

ctrl + shift + i on my build

file -> preferences -> open keyboard shortcuts , "format document"